# How to write inside a panel box using a label?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is the code for writing the letter `G` with `*` representation inside text box. Now I want to write this inside a panel using a label. How can I do it?

I have drawn label box inside panel and want to write inside label.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication31
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form {

    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void A(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      int row, column;

      for (row = 0; row <= 6; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column <= 6; column++) {
          if ((column == 1 && row != 0 && row != 6) || 
              ((row == 0 || row == 6) && column > 1 && column < 5) || 
               (row == 3 && column > 2 && column < 6) || 
               (column == 5 && row != 0 && row != 2 && row != 6))
            textBox1.AppendText("*");
          else
            textBox1.AppendText(" ");
        }

        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
      }
      textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You say "label", but there is `textBox1`.. probably you just want to use `textBox1.Text`.

Comment: Confusing to, `Label box in panel` or  `label in panel box`  or  textbox..

Comment: i have already coded for textBox1....now i want to write this code inside label and this label is present under panel...where is the changes needed

Comment: Why doesn't `label1.Text += "*"` in the same place as `textBox1.AppendText("*")` work?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
Always __TAG__ your question correctly!

Comment: If you do it the way you mentioned in comment, what's the issue you are facing ?

Answer (score 1):

For a TextBox:

```
textBox1.AppendText(text);
```

For a Label:

```
label1.Text += text;
```

Build your text separately using a StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

int row, column;

for (row = 0; row <= 6; row++)
{
    for (column = 0; column <= 6; column++)
    {
        if ((column == 1 && row != 0 && row != 6) ||
            ((row == 0 || row == 6) && column > 1 && column < 5) ||
                (row == 3 && column > 2 && column < 6) ||
                (column == 5 && row != 0 && row != 2 && row != 6))
            builder.Append("*");
        else
            builder.Append(" ");
    }

    builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);

string text = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to do your need using a textbox,

However, label controls are not meant to be multi-line by default. Textboxes can be made like that using the multiline attribute (Hence you need to check compatibility)

Refactor your code as

```
private string CreateGraphicString() {
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int row, column;

  for (row = 0; row <= 6; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column <= 6; column++) {
      if ((column == 1 && row != 0 && row != 6) || 
          ((row == 0 || row == 6) && column > 1 && column < 5) || 
           (row == 3 && column > 2 && column < 6) || 
           (column == 5 && row != 0 && row != 2 && row != 6))
        builder.Append("*");
      else
        builder.Append(" ");
    }

    builder.AppendLine();
  }
  builder.AppendLine();
}
 return builder.ToString();
}

myLabel.Text = builder.AppendLine();
myTextbox.Text = builder.AppendLine();
```